# How to get pointer to start of ndarray data (of any dimension) in cython

Tags: python, cython

I'd like to write a function that operates on a ndarray (of any dimension) in place.

The cython examples I've found like this:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
def c_fill_na_inplace_f64(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, cast=False, mode="c"] X, np.int64_t fillval):
    cdef size_t N = X.size
    cdef np.int64_t* = &X[0]
```

However, I suspect that I need different indexing for differently dimensioned arrays:

```
    cdef np.int64_t* = &X[0]
    cdef np.int64_t* = &X[0,0]
    cdef np.int64_t* = &X[0,0,0]
```

Is there a better way to get the start if the data.

For that matter, how can write a function that takes an ndarray of any dimension? `np.ndarray[ndim=1...` is assumed is `ndim` is not provided.

(NB. I can't use MemoryView because of the const bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the hard part is to get the signature right. I would use generic python-object +`reshape(-1)`, which would reinterpret the array as a one-dimensional array without copying.

Here is a little bit sloppy example. It works at least for continuous arrays, for other arrays it's more complicated, also because C-code must be made aware of it and it is not enough to pass only the pointer `&X[0]`:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
def print_nd(object X):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t] arr=X.reshape(-1)
    cdef np.int64_t *ptr=&arr[0]
    print("addr", <np.uint64_t>(ptr))
    print("ptr1:", ptr[0])
```

Here a test (for 2-dim arrays):

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
def print_2d(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=2] X):
    cdef np.int64_t *ptr=&X[0,0]
    print("addr", <np.uint64_t>(ptr))
    print("ptr1:", ptr[0])

>>> print_nd(a)
addr 94635612809360
ptr1: 1
>>> print_2d(a)
addr 94635612809360
ptr1: 1
```

As you can see, it is the same address in both cases.